# Wordpress - Add file in /inc/ folder using child theme to customize admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm customizing [this](https://github.com/italia/design-comuni-wordpress-theme) wp theme and I need to add a custom tab into the admin dashboard in order to add content to specific pages within the website.

The theme already have a section for this purpose, developed in 14 file stored in the `/inc/admin/options/` folder. The developers use cmb2 to manage the custom fields and they register the options in the file `/inc/admin/options.php`.

I tried to:

- Add in my child theme both the `options.php` file and the new file under the `/inc/admin/options/` folder;
- Overwrite, as suggested in other questions already asked about this issue, the function that register the options in the `functions.php` file in my child theme;
- Require the files in the `functions.php` file;
- Remove and add actions.

Each and everyone of this tests ended up giving me absolutly nothing or critical error without error stack trace.

The only thing that does work it's modifying the parent theme, but it defeats the purpose of the child theme.

In the following screen you can see the "Sotto-categorie Amministrazione", that is the tab I need to add. To make it work, right now, the file is in the parent theme.

[image: wp screenshot]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: https://github.com/italia/design-comuni-wordpress-theme/blob/main/inc/admin/options.php starts by looping over the result of `glob(get_template_directory() . "/inc/admin/options/*.php")`, to include those files. Quote from the docs on `get_template_directory`: _"In the case a child theme is being used, the absolute path to the parent theme directory will be returned."_ - so this will not include any file you put below the `/inc/admin/options/` in your child theme. You will probably have to modify that part, so that it looks for files to include in both places.

Comment: You'll probably also have to take care to not include a file for the same functionality twice. If your child theme tried to overwrite any of the files in `/inc/admin/options/` with its own version, then you'd get a problem with functions being already declared, if the "original" also still gets included.

Comment: @CBroe I tried as you suggested, but it gives me critical error.

Comment: Then you should enable debug mode, to find out the reason.